# Can smart-constructor types have multiple valid Functor instances?

Tags: haskell, constructor, typeclass, functor, parametric-polymorphism

These two rules about `Functor`s are fairly well-known:

1. You can't make a `Functor` if the type parameter appears contravariantly
2. Any type has at most one valid `Functor` instance

But if you cheat slightly, you can break the first rule. Take the Hughes list, for example:

```
data HList a = UnsafeHList ([a] -> [a])

pattern HList a <- UnsafeHList (($ []) -> a)
    where HList a = UnsafeHList (a ++)

instance Functor HList where
    fmap f (HList a) = HList (map f a)

-- instances necessary to make HList useful, but irrelevant to this example, have been omitted
```

As long as you make the assumption that all `HList`s will be made through the smart constructor, that `Functor` instance is lawful, even though `a` appears contravariantly.

My question: can you use a similar technique to break the second rule? Are there any types that have two different valid `Functor` instances if you assume that they'll always be made through smart constructors?

Comment: (ehem) Very incidentally, you can make a difference list functorial without cheating by using Yoneda: `newtype HList a = HList (forall b. (a -> b) -> [b] -> [b])`

Comment: @luqui That one does seem to work and have good asymptotics. I wonder why it's not more popular compared to the smart-constructor approach.

Comment: (co)yoneda is a great trick for functorizing things, under appreciated.  Maybe because it has a scary name (never stopped us before...)

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Suppose you have

```
newtype Foo a = Foo Bool

mkFoo = Foo True
```

Here are its two `Functor` instances:

```
instance Functor Foo where
  fmap _ (Foo x) = Foo x

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap _ !_ = mkFoo
```

Comment: Yep, this looks legit after all, though it still feels unsatisfying for some reason.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, is the edited version more satisfying?

Comment: How is that “smart” instance not equivalent to the “obvious” one? Is it about the strictness? Then you could do the same for any functor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Consider `fmap id (Foo False)`. If not for the smart-constructor restriction, that would be a witness of breaking the identity law.

Comment: "at most one *valid* Functor instance" assumes lawful instances though, that's probably why it feels unsatisfactory.

Comment: The "smart-constructor" restriction prevents you from observng the boolean, which makes that instance observationally equivalent to the obvious one. Basically, they're still kinda the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is quite right. I'd argue that a type isn't actually just a type, but also the equivalence we choose to use on that type. `Foo` can be "completed" with two equivalences: it can have two distinct values or just one. In the first case, the "const" instance is invalid. In the second case, the "identity" and "const" instances are both valid, but... they're also equal. Is there a type (defined by *both* the actual Haskell type *and* the equivalence we want to use on it) that actually has two valid, inequivalent (by that equivalence) `Functor` instances?

Comment: @HTNW, I doubt it very much, but I'm not sure how to prove that. An invalid `Functor` instance must, by parametricity, violate the identity law. Considering the values of the type as representatives can fix that. So we'd need that fix to still violate the composition law. I think that means your abstraction *can't* be mapped faithfully to *any* Haskell type, which seems fairly implausible.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that bang pattern isn't very interesting, but it's necessary to deal with the fact that `mkFoo` is never the *only* way to make a `Foo`—`undefined` is always an option, and we want `fmap id undefined = undefined`.

Comment: After reading the other comments, I realize why I still feel like this is unsatisfying now: the assumption that you have to make for the instance to be valid also prevents you from observing the difference between that instance and the normal one.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, yeah, that's a point. I suspect there's no other way, but I will think on it.